# How to interact with Angular ColorPicker components using Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: java, angular, selenium, testing, primeng

How to interact with Angular ColorPicker components using Selenium WebDriver? There's no text field input for hex codes, and it's operated purely by mouse clicks. An example of it can be seen here: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/colorpicker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting problem.

Well you have the handle object:

div[class*='p-colorpicker-hue-handle']

You can try to drag it via Selenium up or down

For selecting colors you can find the "main" color picker and click not on the center of it, but by giving it offset:

```
String cssExpression = "div[class='ng-trigger-overlayAnimation']
[class='p-colorpicker-panel']";
WebElement element = browser.findElement(By.
cssSelector(cssExpression));
Actions builder = new Actions(browser);
Action action = builder.moveToElement
(element, -20, -20).click().build();
action.perform();
```

You can play with the values and move in the X -50, and in Y -70 for example.

Comment: Thank you. This does indeed allow selenium to interact with the colorpicker. Is there a way to drag the handle more precisely along the Y axis to select specific colors (possibly mapped to strings or hex codes)? I tried the following and it moves the handle upwards by a seemingly random number of pixels, from the bottom of the hue bar to around the middle.


`Action dragHandle = builder.clickAndHold(clrTextColorHueHandle)

                .moveByOffset(0, -10)

                .release()

                .build();`

Comment: @ZakaRiaJanah Hi, I don't know about such an option. You will have to play with offset parameters.